# Liferay set portlet Session value

Tags: session, liferay, portlet

I have 2 portlet, one is MVC Portlet and another is JSF Porlet.
i want to send Attribute from MVC Portlet to another.

in MVC Portlet :

```
@Override
    public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {


        PortletSession portletSession = actionRequest.getPortletSession();
        portletSession.setAttribute("example", "SET ATTR PROCESS ACTION",
                PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
....
```

and in other JSF Portlet :

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest)facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession(false);
String testString = (String) session.getAttribute("example",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

But the value of testString always return null.

Both of 2 portlet have config in liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

I am new with liferay. Thanks for help!

Comment: `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` has been known to cause memory leaks in JSF portlets. Please use an alternative solution from this blog: https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/how-can-i-share-session-data-across-portlets-in-liferay-

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "LIFERAY_SHARED_" before attribute name, i.e.:

```
portletSession.setAttribute("LIFERAY_SHARED_example", "SET ATTR PROCESS ACTION", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

And then read it by the same name:

```
String testString = (String) session.getAttribute("LIFERAY_SHARED_example", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Also, you can change this prefix by specifying it in portal-ext.properties:

```
session.shared.attributes=CUSTOM_PREFIX_
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still return a null value

Comment: When i print session attribute in JSF portlet : 
    `Enumeration en = session.getAttributeNames();`  <br/>

       ` while(en.hasMoreElements()) {`

        ` System.out.println(en.nextElement());`
  `  }`

The result : 

        `javax.portlet.faces.viewIdHistory.view`

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the property ***“private-session-attributes”*** to false in the ***Liferay-portlet.xml*** file of each portlet. Add the following line within the `“<portlet>”` tag :

```
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

Comment: I have put it in liferay-portlet.xml already. you can see it above